# Why does Saturday show up automatically when I use the "TEXT" function in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I've been trying to figure this out for the past two days and it's driving me nuts so I'd greatly appreciate any help with this.

I'm updating a vacation request form so that when someone types in the date (1/22/14 for example) in column C(D) the corresponding day of the week will automatically pop up in column E(FG). I used the following formula: =TEXT(C13, "dddd") but here's where the problem comes in. Some of the rows in the E column are blank (because there's no date typed in column C) but others say "Saturday" and there's no corresponding date to go with it. I want E13-E21 to remain blank until someone puts a date into the corresponding cell (C13-C21). Is there anyway to fix this? I tried attaching a picture so you could see what I'm talking about but "you need at least 10 reputation to post images".

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `IF` to do that, along with a blank check-er.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(C13), "", TEXT(C13, "dddd"))
```

I believe you are getting Saturday, because `1` in excel is equivalent to the date 01/01/1900 which is a Sunday and `0` is thus a day before that, Saturday.

Comment: Right on, TEXT(0,"dddd") is indeed Saturday, apparently the start of the week?!

Comment: @panhandel If Excel's date was based on 2014, `text(1, "dddd")` would give Wednesday (since 01/01/2014 is a Wednesday, I'd expect and `=text(0,"dddd")` to be Tuesday). There's nothing about the start of the week here.

Comment: +1 for the formula. Great way to handle it. `0` equates to `Jan 0, 1900` in Excel's date-speak. Since `Jan 1, 1900` was a Sunday, the day before that is "logically" a Saturday.